# general solution for a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

> > If $L$ is a linear map $L : V \rightarrow W$, and $L(v) = w \in im L$, show that
> >     $$L^{-1}(w) = v + ker L$$
> >     ('im L' is the image of L, and ker L is the kernel of L)

I tried it by using the fact that if  $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, then $A =B$. It is easy to prove $v + ker L \subseteq L^{-1}(w)$. However the inverse is difficult for me to show. Help me to prove $L^{-1}(w) \subseteq v+ ker L$.

comment : I'm studying Linear algebra. I guess that it has relevance to the concept of coset. I have not yet studied it, so want to avoid using the concept as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\;h\in L^{-1}(w)\;$, and write $\;h=v+(h-v)\;$ . Observe that

$$L(h-v)=Lh-Lv=w-w=0\implies h-v\in\ker L$$

and thus $\;h\in v+\ker L\;\implies\;L^{-1}(w)\subset v+\ker L\;$ .

The other direction is almost trivial. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $v\in V$ and consider $w=L(v)\in \text{im}(L)$. We have to calculate $L^{-1}(w)$. By definition, $$L^{-1}(w)=\left\{x\in V\mid L(x)=w=L(v)\right\}.$$
Hence if $x\in L^{-1}(w)$, then $L(x-v)=L(x)-L(v)=0$. Thus $x-v\in \ker(L)$. Equivalently, $x\in \ker(L)+v$, since this holds for all $x\in L^{-1}(w)$, we have shown that $L^{-1}(w)\subset \ker(L)+v$. The other inclusion is easy.